# Difference between Normalized Simultaneous Iteration and Unshifted QR algorithm

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I found that these two methods are very similar and I am confused. What are the differences between them? And I'd appreciate it if you could provide me with an example, carrying out two steps of both of them. Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-335j-introduction-to-numerical-methods-fall-2010/readings/MIT18_335JF10_lec15.pdf) of any help?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much!